# Managing localization strings

Tags: localization

Im investigating different options for managing localized strings. A quick google found a couple of sites where this can be done. The ones I found were http://gengo.com/, http://www.oneskyapp.com/, http://www.icanlocalize.com/ and https://www.transifex.com/.

I would like to hear from someone who has tried them out. Which are the pros and cons of each? And which other sites and tools are there?